# Changing the Return Format of the gallery in Advance Custom Fields ACF Plugin Wordpress using php

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have the old version of ACF (Advanced Custom Fields) Gallery Plugin for Wordpress and there is no option to change the Return format of the gallery from Image Array (which I believe is the default) to Image URL which I need. I was trying to get this sorted using this code but it doesn't work:

```
<?php if( get_field('image') ): ?>
    <img src="<?php the_field('image'); ?>" />
<?php endif; ?>
```

The code I used to implement the plugin into the actual page is this:

```
            <?php 
                $gallery = get_field('gallery');

                if($gallery):?>

                    <?php foreach($gallery as $image): ?>

                        <img src="<?php echo $image;?>" alt="product image" class="img-fluid">

                    <?php endforeach; ?>

            <?php endif; ?>
```

Images are being found but not displayed properly.
[image: view]

[image: screenshot from the newer version of the plugin - which I don't have]

Comment: Just a heads up, any second now someone is going to tell you this should be on wordpress.stackexchange.com!

Answer (score 0):

First, get the image as a variable:

```
$image = get_field('image');
```

Then, take a look at it:

```
if($image):
  print_r($image);
endif;
```

Assuming its all there, choose the field you want with square brackets:

```
$image = get_field('image');
if($image):?>
    <img src="<?php echo $image['url'] ?>" />
<?php endif;
```

Comment: Thank you Djave. I have sorted the problem. I had to update the plugin to pro version.

Answer (score 0):

OK, the solution to do it is to update the plugin to pro version and relevant options appear.